# Add HTML code before the title of the Tag page

Tags: hooks, actions, tags, the-content, get-the-title

I want to show an `iframe` at the top of a specific Tag page, so once I have `is_tag('my_tag')`, I will add the `iframe` before the `title` of the page.

I've tried this code to show the iframe before the content of the page, but it didn't work:

```php
// Show the iFrame at the beginning of the page
function show_iframe($content) {
    if ( is_tag('my_tag') ) {
        $before = '<iframe src="https://www.example.com" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>';
        return $before . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'show_iframe');
```

Is there any hook that runs before printing the title of the page? or any way to `echo` an `HTML` code before a chosen `div` in the page?

Comment: You can edit the template file directly as your `iframe` does not depend on any dynamic data.

Comment: I don't want to touch the original files of the theme or WordPress core.

Answer (score 0):

First, in WordPress lingo 'content' does not include 'title'. (Also, be careful with 'title'. Sometimes it means 'the heading above the main content, and below the site navigation and/or masthead', and sometimes it means the html title, which is a piece of text the browser shows at the top of the window or tab, in its history, etc. In this case, it sounds like you're referring to the former.

Second, in this case there isn't a hook to modify the title. Instead, modify a template. You might worry that you'd have to modify several template files, since web pages for the site will look different. Fortunately, usually, for consistency the top part of different kinds of web pages will look the same. So, you probably just have to modify `header.php` or some template part (probably in `template-parts/header`).

Comment: Can we do something without modifying the files of the theme? Like adding an action or something to the `functions.php` file?

Comment: One clarification: there are title modification hooks, but I don't think just prepending your html will work. Anyway, yes, you shouldn't modify a third-party theme directly. That's what child themes are for. By modifying its `functions.php` you're already modifying the theme. That said, copying-and-modifying archive templates might be problematic because they're might be several. So instead I'm proposing a jQuery solution, which I'm adding separately. Time permitting, I'll see if there's a workable PHP solution.

Comment: Thanks @LorenRosen, using a jQuery script seems to be the only solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript in the browser. Here's a jQuery solution. Note the details depend on the theme details, your tags, desired iframe url, etc.

In `functions.php` add

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('title-tweak',
                      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/title-tweak.js',
                      array('jquery'));

}
```

and make the file (in your theme) `js/title-tweak.js`, containing

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            if ($("body").hasClass("tag-my_tag")) {
                $(".page-title").before ('<iframe src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar"></iframe>');
            }

        } ); 
})(jQuery);
```

**Addendum**
I did it a slightly more complicated way, because at one time the simpler way didn't work. But (at least on my browser) it does now.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
                $(".body.tag-my_tag page-title").before ('<iframe src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar"></iframe>');
        } ); 
})(jQuery);
```